# How to group data by date and display in html table using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'am new to programming and I stumble upon on grouping data by date and display them in a table with a date separator.

Here is mysql data:
[image]

How do I group the data into dates and display it in a html table like the one below.
[image]

I know how to get the data from database and display them in a html table, however grouping data by date seems completely not easy for me I'm a beginner to php programming. I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: If you can share the code you are already using to get the data from the database and display them in the table it will be easier to figure out a way to change the output to match your requirements.

Comment: first read the table and fetch data, then use a foreach to echo out data, inside the loop, echo out the date first, then check if there's any other rows with same date value and echo them out next. loop through this and you'll get what you need.styling/css and html can be done as you like

Comment: You should share your code and your errors to help us to help you. and follow up your question otherwise why we should follow up you?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice I will write the code and share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output being shown:

[image] Created an array with provided the data and looped over the data.

The key is use array key values.

The main array should have `date` as a key and append all the employee rows to it.

The array structure should be:

```
Array
(
    [19/04/19] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [idno] => 111
                    [date] => 19/04/19
                    [employee] => MAYER CU
                    [timein] => 8:00:00 AM
                    [timeout] => 6:54:00 PM
                    [totalhours] => 10:54
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [idno] => 111
                    [date] => 19/04/19
                    [employee] => MAYER CU
                    [timein] => 10:00:00 AM
                    [timeout] => 6:00:00 PM
                    [totalhours] => 8
                )

        )

    [20/04/19] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [idno] => 111
                    [date] => 20/04/19
                    [employee] => MIKE SMITH
                    [timein] => 9:01:00 AM
                    [timeout] => 6:54:00 PM
                    [totalhours] => 9:53
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [idno] => 111
                    [date] => 20/04/19
                    [employee] => MIKE SMITH
                    [timein] => 10:00:00 AM
                    [timeout] => 6:55:00 PM
                    [totalhours] => 8:55
                )

        )

)
```

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$arr = [];
$arr[] = ['id' => 1, 'idno' => 111, 'date'=> '19/04/19', 'employee' => 'MAYER CU', 'timein' => '8:00:00 AM', 'timeout' => '6:54:00 PM', 'totalhours' => '10:54'];
$arr[] = ['id' => 2, 'idno' => 111, 'date'=> '19/04/19', 'employee' => 'MAYER CU', 'timein' => '10:00:00 AM', 'timeout' => '6:00:00 PM', 'totalhours' => '8'];
$arr[] = ['id' => 3, 'idno' => 111, 'date'=> '20/04/19', 'employee' => 'MIKE SMITH', 'timein' => '9:01:00 AM', 'timeout' => '6:54:00 PM', 'totalhours' => '9:53'];
$arr[] = ['id' => 4, 'idno' => 111, 'date'=> '20/04/19', 'employee' => 'MIKE SMITH', 'timein' => '10:00:00 AM', 'timeout' => '6:55:00 PM', 'totalhours' => '8:55'];

$arrDisplay = [];
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $employee) {
  $arrDisplay[$employee['date']][] = $employee;
 }
}
//echo '<pre>';print_r($arrDisplay);echo '</pre>';
?>
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<?
if (! empty($arrDisplay)) {
 foreach ($arrDisplay as $date => $employees) {
 ?>
 <tr>
<td colspan="7" align="center"><?php echo $date;?></td>
</tr>
<?
if (! empty($employees)) {
 foreach ($employees as $employee) {
?>
 <tr>
 <?
if (! empty($employee)) {
 foreach ($employee as $employeeData) {
 ?>
<td><?php echo $employeeData;?></td>
<?
}
}
?>
</tr>
<?
 }
}
 }
}
?>
</table>
```